# How to set constraint programatically plus constant?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, constraints

I want my button to be 200 above the center. My code errors:

```
docButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor + 200),
```

with

```
Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'NSLayoutYAxisAnchor' and 'Int'
```

How can I set a button to be some amount above the center?

Also, I want to set a single back button. How can I set a button's constraints to be 20 points below the top safe area and 20 points right of the left safe area?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `docButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor, constant: 200)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
docButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor,constant:-200) // -200 above the center?
```

For leading with safeArea

```
docButton.leadingnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingnchor,constant:20)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How about in relation to the safe view (boundaries) of my phone?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this Link on Apple Docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutyaxisanchor

1. you are trying to add 200 to a non-Integer type (NSLayoutYAxisAnchor).
2. you can use this:
   `cancelButton.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(saveButton.topAnchor, constant: -200).active = true`